# PHP setcookie function not being set on wordpress splash page implementation

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

So I'm trying to get a splash page implemented on a wordpress site. I've looked around and read about how to do it using PHP. The idea of the splash page is to redirect people that haven't viewed the site to a splash page that encourages them to donate. The page is already set to a static homepage which I am making the splash page be. Provided here is the code that I have for the cookie, for some reason when I go into my settings on chrome and check to see if the cookie is being written it doesn't show up.

```
<?php
  if((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], get_bloginfo('home')) === false)  && !$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] && $_COOKIE["CookieName"] != 'true') :
  setcookie("CookieName", 'true', time() + 3600*24*15, "/~user/");
?>
//splash page code
<?php else : ?> //theme code <?php endif; ?>
```

The else condition is the information for the homepage that was created by the theme. The URL for the site is in the format of `siteIP/~user/`. If you guys have some feed back that would be greatly appreciated. Also if you can provide a source so that I can read up on it that would also be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "The idea of the splash page is to redirect people that haven't viewed the site to a splash page that encourages them to donate." Not an answer at all, but are you sure you want to annoy your visitors?

Comment: I'm willing to place money on this being `Warning: Cannot Modify Header Information - Headers Already Sent`, because you have already output some data before this point in the code is reached. I say that because of the random mish-mash of `<?php ?>` tags littered throughout the code.

Comment: You have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) enabled right?

Comment: This is something that a client, who happens to be a politician, has requested. So they want it to go to the splash page if you're visiting the site for the first time. There is an option to skip to the site on the splash page.

Comment: @DaveRandom I removed the `<?php ?>` tags where the cookie is being set and that didn't help at all. @PeeHaa I haven't setup error reporting because I have never seen it before in all honesty. Can I put the error reporting code wherever I want in terms of trouble shooting or will it throw off the cookies Also where does the function write to so I have a reference point of where to look.

Comment: @Elias [Enable error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it didn't work is because there was a file that was overwriting the splash page itself so the code on the splash page wasn't being called in the first place. It's a matter of just naming files so that it doesn't have any additional files overwriting it the content that you put up there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting an answer but I can't comment because I don't have the rep.

Besides reviewing the comments above, try simplifying - check that the if statement is being executed, then you'll know if you have an error in the cookie setting.

Also, your code as quoted doesn't have a closing  statement, I assume you have that in the actual page but thought I would mention that.

Comment: yeah, I just added that to the code. Thanks for putting that in there. I had the closing statement on the code just forgot to add it here. -- EDIT the code is going straight to the else statement, and passing the if. It's not executing anything within the if statement.

Comment: @Elias I think you need to do some basic debugging if it goes straight to the `else` part of your condition. I.e. `var_dump();` all variables in your `if` statement to verify it contains what yuo think it does.

Comment: I got a solution. Thanks though. There was wordpress code that overrode the splash code that i tried to implement.